# MapIcon image property in Windows Phone 8.1 make app crash?

Tags: windows, win-phone-silverlight-8.1

I have problem with MapIcon image property in Windows Phone 8.1
LocationIcon.Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/icon/location_icon.png"));

using it make my app crash, but i need to show the location icon when using GPS, why?